# How make the menuitem full width on SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, menu

In phones, I wanna a menu where the items span the full width on-screen but look like the size is fixed?

```swift
public struct MenuDropdown: View {
    let menu: [MenuItem]

    public init(menu: [MenuItem]) {
        self.menu = menu
    }

    func doMenu() {}

    public var body: some View {
        Menu {
            ForEach(self.menu, id: \.module) { row in
                Button(action: doMenu) {
                    Label(row.module, systemImage: "doc").frame(minWidth: 0,
                                                                maxWidth: .infinity)
                }.frame(minWidth: 0,
                        maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        } label: {
            Label("Options", systemImage: "hamburger")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't it is very limited. A `List` looks similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Picker inside a Form or List inside a NavigationView. This will show the options full width in an extra view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form { // or List
                Picker(selection: $selected) {
                    ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { row in
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("\(row)", systemImage: "doc")
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    Label("Options", systemImage: "heart")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```